# order by rand() gets trouble for large posts

Tags: php, mysql, random, sql-order-by

I have this code, this code gets trouble and so much time to be executed to show RANDOM posts from DB:

```
$totalrows = 10;

$sql = "SELECT 
 posts.Tags as tags, 
 posts.OwnerUserId as postsid, 
 posts.Id as postid, 
 posts.Body as body, 
 posts.Title as title, 
 users.Id as userid, 
 users.DisplayName as usersname  
FROM posts 
JOIN users ON posts.OwnerUserId = users.Id 
WHERE posts.Title != '' order by rand() asc limit " .  $totalrows;

$r = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Please tell me what should I change to show random posts more quikly?

Regards,Dan

Comment: The performance of `ORDER BY RAND()` has been shown to be inherently bad, see http://www.dasprids.de/blog/2008/06/07/fetching-random-rows-of-mysql-efficiently

Comment: How to change my php code please

Answer (score 2):

rand() is very expensive. This will help: http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/

Comment: Although note the caveats with that approach. A secondary index on a scheduled "compacted id sequence" value or an indirect table can deal with the issue of many missing sequential ids -- or can work even if no sequential id can be assumed.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $sql = "select posts.id from posts where posts.title != '' order by rand() asc limit " . $totalrows;

 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

 $tmpArray = array();

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $tmpArray[] = $row['id']; // This will add all items to array
 }

 $csvResult = implode(',',$tmpArray);

 $sql = " select posts.*, users.* From posts join users on posts.owneruserid  = user.id where posts.id in (" . $csvResult . ")";

 $r = mysql_query($sql) or  die(mysql_error());
```

*Please check for any typos and column names.*

Comment: Please split the queries, in my last answer I told you, but when you posted the query back it is not split. In first query we get 10 random IDs and in second query we just get other details against these 10 random results.

Comment: `$sql = " select posts.*, users.* From posts join users on posts.owneruserid  = user.id where posts.id in (" . $csvResult . ")";`
 was missing last `"`

Comment: Hi Amir,
Thanks for update. The script show now the page but instead for the Title show only "No title" for Title name

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the means of testing this right now but it should give pretty uniform distribution, and I doubt speed will be an issue.  Pick some random numbers ONCE in PHP and do some simple modulus operation that should be "random enough" to order your rows.

If the exact numbers I've chosen don't give good results you can probably choose some that will.

```
$totalrows = 10;  
$m = rand(31,61);
$k = randint(10,20);
$offset = rand(200,500) % $m;

$sql = ... "ORDER BY (post_id + $offset + $k*(post_id MOD 8)) MOD $m LIMIT $totalRows";

$r = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

If this is still too slow you can try putting some basic randomness into the WHERE clause as a 'coarse' filter so not so many rows have to be ordered.  However, keep in mind that it should be simpler than whatever you do in ORDER BY or you'll just be doing the same slow operations again.

Let me know if this works for you, im curious and wish I could test it myself in SQL.  Distributions look pretty good with my trying something similar in Python for the set of 'id's 1-20000, but that doesnt tell me anything about speed of execution in SQL

Comment: Hello Jon,
I get Fatal error: Call to undefined function randint()

Comment: o sorry, just `rand` not `randint`.  also, ive found that some of those value should be hardcoded instead of random, ill change soon

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is.

1. You need to get 10 randome posts
2. You need to get the name of the person who posted
3. They should be random but the join makes it time taking.

I suggest you to split them,

`$sql = "select posts.id where posts.title != '' order by rand() asc limit " .  $totalrows;`

execute the result and then implode the result in csv formate
`$csvResult = 2,3,4,5` these numbers are the IDs of the random posts.
In your 2nd query

`$sql = " select posts.*, users.* From posts join users on posts.owneruserid = user.id where posts.id in (" . $csvResult . ");`

`$r = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Hope this will reduce the time.

Comment: I followed your advice and I get this error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where posts.Title != '' order by rand() asc limit 10' at line 1

Comment: What MySQL version you are using. I just tested on my db `select section_id from mc_sections where section_nick != '' order by rand() asc limit 2` and it did worked

Comment: I had posted `$sql = "select posts.id where posts.title != '' order by rand() asc limit " . $totalrows;` but it is not having any FROM please correct it `$sql = "select posts.id from posts where posts.title != '' order by rand() asc limit " . $totalrows;`

Comment: Also please add index on your columns which you are fetching in first query, In this case. ID, and TITLE

Comment: require 15 reputation and I dont havethis rep

Answer (score 0):

One more way

```
$totalrows = 10;

$sql = "SELECT 
 posts.Tags as tags, 
 posts.OwnerUserId as postsid, 
 posts.Id as postid, 
 posts.Body as body, 
 posts.Title as title, 
 users.Id as userid, 
 users.DisplayName as usersname  
FROM posts 
JOIN users ON posts.OwnerUserId = users.Id 
JOIN (select posts.id from posts where posts.title != '' order by rand() asc limit " . $totalrows .") AS tmp_result
ON (posts.Id = tmp_result.Id)";


$r = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Hmm I dont know if this will speed up your script :D it totally depends upon your records now.

Comment: Hello Amir, this solution is excelent. Thanks so much Sir!

Comment: Dear Aamri, I used the above script but its getting trouble in MySql, I think make too many persistent connection and its freezing the server and require restarting. What should I add to limit it or add a time out for connection? What solution should I include?

Comment: I tried to do it in a single query... please refer to my other answer, to split this one query into two.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644600/order-by-rand-gets-trouble-for-large-posts/4646127#4646127 you can not just copy the code which I had posted so alter it and remove any typing mistakes.