# query problems with order by rand

Tags: mysql, performance

```
$totalrows = 10;

$sql = "SELECT 
 posts.Tags as tags, 
 posts.OwnerUserId as postsid, 
 posts.Id as postid, 
 posts.Body as body, 
 posts.Title as title, 
 users.Id as userid, 
 users.DisplayName as usersname  
FROM posts 
JOIN users ON posts.OwnerUserId = users.Id 
WHERE posts.Title != '' order by rand() asc limit " .  $totalrows;

$r = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Any suggestion to speed php?

Comment: Um you just asked this exact question earlier. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644600/order-by-rand-gets-trouble-for-large-posts

Answer (score 2):

See this presentation from Bill Karwin. Slide 142 and onwards.

http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back

Answer (score 0):

Check this...
$limit = 10;
$start = 0;
$sql = "SELECT 
 posts.Tags as tags, 
 posts.OwnerUserId as postsid, 
 posts.Id as postid, 
 posts.Body as body, 
 posts.Title as title, 
 users.Id as userid, 
 users.DisplayName as usersname
FROM posts 
JOIN users ON posts.OwnerUserId = users.Id 
WHERE posts.Title != '' order by rand() asc limit " . $start . " , " .  $limit;

$r = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Hello,

I tryed your advice, its get 30 seconds to be opened